# Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'urn:UmbracoHelper'

Tags: c#, css, xslt, umbraco

I am developing under Umbraco 4.8.

I am trying to access to a class from my XSLT to retrieve something from it.
The class is named UmbracoHelper.
I have added followings to the top of my XSLT:

- xmlns:UmbracoHelper="urn:UmbracoHelper"
- exclude-result-prefixes "UmbracoHelper"

But now when I want to call the function as below :

```
<xsl:for-each select="$GalleryImages/nodeId">
<xsl:variable name="myNode" select="UmbracoHelper:GetNode(.)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am facing this error:

**Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'urn:UmbracoHelper'.**

What have I missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: write your code and build (UmbracoHelper). Add assembly to bin folder. Make sure that you add a reference to your assembly in xsltextensions.config. And then reference via urn in your XSLT.

See: http://www.nibble.be/?p=60

Answer (score 1):

Actually while Jonathan's answer is correct, that method is slightly deprecated.

An easier way to do this is to add a reference to umbraco.dll in your solution. Then, you can decorate your class using the `[RestExtension("TestAlias")]
    [XsltExtension]` attributes, as seen [here](http://www.nibble.be/?p=95). You can then drop the .cs file in the App_Data folder, or compile it and drop the dll file in the bin directory of your Umbraco installation. The advantage of this method is that it takes away the need to edit the config files yourself.

Comment: I tried it and replace the TestAlias with UmbracoHelper, but still not working.
Have I missed something again?

Comment: did you add the [XsltExtension] decoration as well?